¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error en java? Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
espero puedan responderme pronto, el código lo que realiza es crear un vector de X elementos y que al ingresar los elemento, concluir si el Vector esta ordenado o desordenado, pero con la peculiaridad de que siempre debe salir el primer mensaje de que el vector esta vacío. Este es el código:
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Aguilar Nava Said Antonio
 */
public class Vector_lleno_vacio {
public static int x,vec;
public static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
public static boolean okiss;
public static int[]vector = null;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (vector == null){
        System.out.println("El arreglo esta vacio");
        System.out.println("Ingrese tamaño de su arreglo");
        x = sc.nextInt();
        vector = new int [x];
        vec = vector.length;
        Insertar_datos(vector);
        Ordenado_o_no(vector);
        }
   }
    
    public static void Insertar_datos(int vector[]){
      System.out.println("Ingrese dato al arreglo:");
      for(x=0; x<vec; x++){
       vector[x] = sc.nextInt();
      }
    }
    
    public static void Ordenado_o_no(int vector[]){
      okiss = false;
      for(x=0; x<vec; x++){
        if(vector[x] < vector[x+1]){
          okiss = true;
        }else{
          okiss=false;
          System.out.println("El arreglo esta desorenado");
          break;
        }
      }
        if(okiss==true){
          System.out.println("El arreglo esta ordenado");
        } 
    }
}

Al ejecutar el código e ingresar por ejemplo el tamaño del vector es 4, si escribes en orden, saltara el error, pero al escribirlo desordenado, compilara sin problemas. Aquí la muestra.
El arreglo esta vacio
Ingrese tama�o de su arreglo
4
Ingrese dato al arreglo:
1
2
3
4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4

El arreglo esta vacio
Ingrese tama�o de su arreglo
4
Ingrese dato al arreglo:
1
2
4
3
El arreglo esta desorenado
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Tu problema es esta linea
if(vector[x] < vector[x+1]){

si tu vector tiene 4 elementos.. sus elementos son vector[0] hasta vector[3] ..
si metes ese if dentro de un for que va de 0 a 3... cuando estes en el elemento 3, vas a comparar el elemento 3... con el 4 que no existe!!!!
no pasa caundo esta desordenado, porque sale antes ;)
Soluciòn rapidisima... cambia el for a
for(x=0; x<vec-1; x++){

Porque el ultimo elemento no te interesa porque ya lo miraste con el anteultimo para saber si estaba ordenado, y si no, va a quedar desordenado de por si...

Claaaaaro, si funcionó amigo, muchas gracias, porque no lo ví antes, me salvaste
